# python map array of dictionaries to dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary, mapping

I've got an array of dictionaries that looks like this:

```
[
  { 'country': 'UK', 'city': 'Manchester' },
  { 'country': 'UK', 'city': 'Liverpool' },
  { 'country': 'France', 'city': 'Paris' } ...
]
```

And I want to end up with a dictionary like this:

```
{ 'Liverpool': 'UK', 'Manchester': 'UK', ... }
```

Obviously I can do this:

```
 d = {}
 for c in cities:
     d[c['city']] = c['country']
```

But is there any way I could do it with a single-line map?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a [*dict comprehension*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) :

```
>>> li = [
...   { 'country': 'UK', 'city': 'Manchester' },
...   { 'country': 'UK', 'city': 'Liverpool' },
...   { 'country': 'France', 'city': 'Paris' }
... ]

>>> {d['city']: d['country'] for d in li}
{'Paris': 'France', 'Liverpool': 'UK', 'Manchester': 'UK'}
```

Or us `operator.itemgetter` and `map` function :

```
>>> dict(map(operator.itemgetter('city','country'),li))
{'Paris': 'France', 'Liverpool': 'UK', 'Manchester': 'UK'}
```